# Big Data Environment: Set up Hadoop - MongoDB structure

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, sqoop

I read lots of documentations about `Big Data` and especially about `Hadoop` ecosystem.

### Objective :

Thanks to my job, I have to deploy a Big Data structure in order to collect data from `RDBMS` (`Oracle Database` for example) and make many things with `MapReduce` process to improve turnover, benefits from my client.

So I have to imagine my Big Data Environment to do that.

### Hardware :

Before to set this project in production, I can make some tries into my company hardware. To do that, I will simulate each node by VMs. I have maybe 4-5 To to store data into HDD and I have about 32 Gb of RAM.

This environment is very bad, but the first step is to install each part, connectors and see if the entire project could work before to make the same thing to my production environment.

In this one, each VM will be a server.

### What I would like to use :

I'm thinking about my structure and which softwares I have to use in order to realize my project.

***Oracle Database :***

To begin, initial data will be often store into an `Oracle Database`. BUT data type could be very various : int/char/float, pictures, movies, ... It could be financial data, authenticate data, ...

***Sqoop :***

I didn't never use `Sqoop`, but I assume it's a very good tool in order to import data from Oracle Database to HDFS.

***MongoDB :***

So I would like to use `MongoDB` in order to store data from HDFS.

Why ? Because MongoDB is well-adapted to various data type, powerful query operators, comparison , .. and Python drivers. Very low recovery time too.

***MongoDB Connector for Hadoop :***

My MongoDB choice is justified because it exists a connector between MongoDB and Hadoop. I didn't never use this connector, but I assume this connector let to do the job ?

***Hadoop :***

The most Big Data environment known. I will set up 3 nodes (VM's) in order to make some tries. The first node (Namenode) with `HDFS/YARN` then 2 nodes (Datanodes) with MapReduce process. Maybe I will set up a fourth node according to the secondary namenode (not necessary into my testing environment).

***Which tool to make reporting ?***

I read some documentations about `Spark` but I don't know if this tool lets to make reporting ?

### Global scheme

I made a global scheme in order to illustrate my Big Data Environment

[image]

### Some questions about my project

1. Does the project seem to be coherent for you ?
2. The MapReduce process takes data from HDFS Hadoop or MongoDB ?
3. Which tool is necessary in order to make reporting with MapReduce results ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

If my question should be post elsewhere, please tell me because I don't find the good place.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question doesn't fit into StackOverflow standards. It's too broad to answer, as well as opinionated and is likely to be closed. BTW, why MapReduce? Why not Spark?

Comment: @philantrovert Thank you for your answer. There is a better place in order to discuss about Hadoop project in StackOverflow ? I don't know the difference between MapReduce and Spark in order to process data.

Comment: You can think of Spark as a better, faster and more versatile version of Mapreduce. I would suggest heading over to https://spark.apache.org and reading the basics and how Spark works. Then you can further analyze if you can fit it into your project or not.

Comment: Spark also has an in-built JDBC reader. So you can also cut the need of using Sqoop. You can directly go ahead and read the table on Oracle using Spark, perform whatever transformations on it that you want to perform and then you can get the output as a file on HDFS or as a hive table or even as a new Oracle table.

Comment: @philantrovert Ok I will read about Spark solution and How I could structure my Big Data environment thanks to Spark. So MongoDB should stay into my global scheme or it's not necessary from your point of view ?

Comment: Spark also reads from MongoDB. By the way

Comment: Anyways, you're use case is too vague. Customer turn over meaning what?  2 datanodes will not really show you the benefits of offloading an Oracle database into Hadoop, regardless of what tools you use to do it with. 5 datanodes w/ NodeManagers would be my recommended minimum. And not running in VMs on a single machine would be preferred

Comment: Regarding using Spark for reporting, yes. It offers a JDBC server for running SQL queries, but you need to tune your cluster resources very high on memory  to get really quick results for your reporting applications. Hive2.x, Apache Drill, and PrestoDB are other options for reporting (SQL) applications. MapReduce should not be used period for quick results. Couchbase and Cassandra are arguably more scalable than Mongo for large datasets

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you with your very detailled answer ! My use case is vague, but the presented hardware is just for installing and testing this environment. Then, I will install the same ecosystem into the production environment. It's a bit vague because I'm learning about this domain and it's why I asked some questions here ;) In production, I will have at least 5 or 6 nodes in order to make a very interesting ecosystem. Maybe it's possible to discuss together because I have 2-3 questions about softwares ? Thank you anyway

Comment: I've already voted to close this question as too broad, but if you isolate to a smaller section of the architecture,  and post a new question, then it might be worth answering. Also, Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Architecture and design should be posted on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour